# IE drop down menu problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

From what I can see it only happens in IE9 and only when the compatibility mode is on.  I asked one of my friends to take a look and it works fine on his PC in IE9, so it looks like it may be isolated to certain OSs too.

Drop-down appears under the wrong top-level menu -[image]

The site can be seen here - http://www.traffic-club.org/

I have been looking at CSS and from what I can see everything is kosher. I appreciate any feedback you may have!

Comment: Does your friend have the same size screen as you?

Comment: This is an issue when running IE7 as well, not just IE9 compatibility mode.

Comment: Please don't mask your links.

Comment: Try fixing these validation errors first to make sure it's not a markup problem. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.traffic-club.org%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, a good solution to this problem is this:

Add `position: relative;` to your `li`s that have a dropdown menu anf set the `left` property to `0` (not `auto`) when a user hovers the link.

Its line 121 in your css file:

`left: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

**Confirmed, this is an issue that stems from IE7.**  You could use a CSS selector for IE to make slight CSS modifications specifically for the browsers giving you the issue.

Start here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/, this should set you on the right path.

Of course, **you should still make sure your code is all correctly validated**.  But sometimes IE doesn't listen regardless of that and this is a solution that could come in handy in the future as well.